# retrieve all customers email address stripe node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this function that tries to retrieve all the customer's emails in stripe:

```
 const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
  });

    var customerEmail = customers.data[0].email;
    console.log(customerEmail)
```

I am trying to return all the email addresses of the users from stripe. the problem is, when I log it, it only returns the first one, due to teh fact that I have `data[0]`. I need all of them, but i can't put it in a loop because what am i looping through. is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: what does customers.data contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property you are indexing is an array you can iterate through[1].

```
const customers = await stripe.customers.list({});

customers.data.forEach(customer => {
  console.log(customer.email);
});
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list

Comment: thanks for your response. however, when I just ran this, it gave me a type error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: customers.forEach is not a function`. ?

Comment: Apologies, that should have been `customers.data.forEach`. Edited my answer.

Comment: no worries. I appreciate your help, thank you :)